# Another javascript array alphabetical sorting hardtime

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, jscript, alphabetical

I have an `array` that looks like this, how can I sort it alphabetically without loosing the key?

```
var items = [
  { 11: 'Edward' },
  { 12: 'Sharpe' },
  { 13: 'Alvin' }
];
```

Comment: Does all object have only 1 key-value pair?

Comment: yes, numbers are keys, and names are values..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can sort the `items` array using `Object.values`.

```js
const items = [
  { 11: 'Edward' },
  { 12: 'Sharpe' },
  { 13: 'Alvin' }
];

items.sort((a, b) => Object.values(a)[0] > Object.values(b)[0]);

console.log(items);
```

Comment: Nice solution, will fail though on [`Internet Explorer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values).

Answer (score 6):

If the objects have only one key, then you can use `Object.keys` to retrieve that key an then sort:

```js
var items = [
  { '11': 'Edward' },
  { '12': 'Sharpe' },
  { '13': 'Alvin' }
];

items.sort(function(a, b) {
  var akey = Object.keys(a) [0],           // get a's key
      bkey = Object.keys(b) [0];           // get b's key
      
  return a[akey].localeCompare(b[bkey]);   // compare the values using those keys
});

console.log(items);
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `Object.keys`, since they only have one value we don't know, we can use the length property minus one to get the actual key reference.

```js
var items = [
  { 11: 'Edward' },
  { 12: 'Sharpe' },
  { 13: 'Alvin' }
];

items.sort(function(a, b){
 var c = Object.keys(a);
 var d = Object.keys(b);
 return a[c[c.length-1]] > b[d[d.length-1]] ? 1: -1;
 }
)

console.log(items);
```